# How to create maximum 8 <input type="button"> with value A, B, C and so on?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create, at max, 8 buttons and I am successful at that, but I want to give the values to the buttons as A, B, C and so on..
Here is the code that I have done so far:

```
var buttonValue = 1;
function addButton(){
   if(buttonValue <=8){
      var targetDiv = document.getElementById('targetDiv');
      var inputField = document.createElement('INPUT');
      inputField.setAttribute('type','button');
      inputField.setAttribute('id',"input-"+buttonValue+"");
      inputField.setAttribute('class','controls');
      targetDiv.append(inputField);      
   }
   buttonValue++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I want to give the values to the buttons as A, B, C and so on.

The character code for `A` is 65 (`"A".charCodeAt(0)`). So you can use `String.fromCharCode` to create your values by adding `buttonValue - 1` to `65`:

```
inputField.setAttribute("value", String.fromCharCode(65 + buttonValue - 1));
// or
inputField.defaultValue = String.fromCharCode(65 + buttonValue - 1);
// or
inputField.value = String.fromCharCode(65 + buttonValue - 1);
// See below for details on .value vs. .defaultValue
```

---

BTW, you can save a fair bit of typing by using the reflected properties for the `type`, `id`, and `class` attributes:

```
inputField.type = 'text';
inputField.id = "input-" + buttonValue;
inputField.className = 'controls';
//         ^^^^^^^^^ Note the slightly-different name
```

(Also note that `+""` is unnecessary in your `id` code.)

For `value`, it's a bit complicated:

- `.value = ...` sets the **current value** of the input, which is **not** the same thing as the `value` attribute
- The `value` *attribute* sets the *default value* of the input, not its current value.
- The reflected property for the value *attribute* is `defaultValue`, not `value`

Comment: Just the answer I was trying to find. Thank you for this extensive answer. It does not only clarifies my problem but also some extra knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the value to a string, with an offset.

BTW, you need a `while` loop for getting all buttons and you need `appendChild` to append the button to the div.

> What you get
>
> ```
> <div id="targetDiv">
>     <input id="input-1" type="button" value="A">
>     <input id="input-2" type="button" value="B">
>     <input id="input-3" type="button" value="C">
>     <input id="input-4" type="button" value="D">
>     <input id="input-5" type="button" value="E">
>     <input id="input-6" type="button" value="F">
>     <input id="input-7" type="button" value="G">
>     <input id="input-8" type="button" value="H">
> </div>
> ```

```js
function addButton() {
    var buttonValue = 1,
        targetDiv = document.getElementById('targetDiv'),
        inputField;
    while (buttonValue <= 8) {
        inputField = document.createElement('input');
        inputField.type = 'button';
        inputField.id = "input-" + buttonValue;
        inputField.value = (buttonValue + 9).toString(36).toUpperCase();
        targetDiv.appendChild(inputField);
        buttonValue++;
    }
}

addButton();
```

```html
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
```